# Admin LTE with Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using Laratrust and try implements:
I created these files

App\MyMenuFilter.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Builder;
use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\FilterInterface;

class MyMenuFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function transform($item, Builder $builder)
    {
        if (isset($item['permission']) && Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

I changed this
config\adminlte.php

```
'menu' => [
    'MAIN NAVIGATION',
    [
        'text' => 'Blog',
        'url'  => 'admin/blog',
        'permission'  => 'create-post', // Here
    ],
    #code
]

'filters' => [
    #code
    //JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\GateFilter::class,
    App\MyMenuFilter::class,
],
```

But show this error:

Class 'App\Laratrust' not found (View: /var/www/html/multi-auth/vendor/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte/resources/views/page.blade.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way

```
if (isset($item['permission']) && \Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
            return false;
}
```

or you can

```
use Laratrust;

if (isset($item['permission']) && Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
      return false;
}
```

the use statement should be right at the top before class definition and the condition will obviously be in your method

It appears that Laratrust is a package residing in vendor directory thats why trying to get it under the \App location will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You dont import the `App\Laratrust` in your namespace. Add `use App\Laratrust;` to the top of your class and it should work.